# How to join tables with same name in different schemas

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to check the difference between data in two tables that have same name but are in different schema. I have two schema : Database1 and Database2 , in first schema I have TABLE_TEST and iN the second schema the TABLE_TEST too. Datas inside the table-s have some difference between each other . I need to find which are those differences . What I have tried is the query above but it  throws this error

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

```
SELECT *
FROM Database1.TABLE_TEST 
  INNER JOIN Database2.TABLE_TEST 
          ON Database1.TABLE_TEST.ID = Database2.TABLE_TEST.ID;
```

How does the table look and what I need to display as differences

[image: How does the table look and what I need to display as differences]

Comment: Do you have two schemas or two databases? Those are two very different things. If those are indeed schemas (=users) then the oracle user you are using to run the query needs to have select privilege on all tables - including the ones not owned by that account.

Comment: two schemas, dont mind the names :)

Comment: Inner join won't find rows which have different `id`, in your example 2 and 4. You need `full join` if you want to see them. And use aliases to make syntax more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you are connected as `DATABASE1` user.

`DATABASE2` user has to

```
grant select on table_test to database1;
```

so that `database1` could select its data.

Then, query you wrote should be working OK (`database1` prefix isn't necessary, but won't do any harm).

```
SELECT *
FROM Database1.TABLE_TEST 
  INNER JOIN Database2.TABLE_TEST 
          ON Database1.TABLE_TEST.ID = Database2.TABLE_TEST.ID;
```

Comment: If I try this in Database 2 : grant select on table_test to database1; this ERROR occurs "user or role '%s' does not exist". I change it in: grant select on TABLE_TEST to userDb1; with the name of user of database1 and Grant succeeded appeared. But when I compile the query that I have write before the problem consist again in knowing Database2.TABLE_TEST. Throwing this exception : 00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: That approach works if you do it right. I know only what you tell us. If you use generic names, don't expect us to read your mind. I don't have a crystal ball. Please, edit the initial message and copy/paste your SQL Plus session so that we could see what you EXACTLY did and how Oracle responded.